# more than usually

Tags: adverbs, comparative-constructions

Can one use (a) instead of (b)?

a. He worked more rapidly than usually.

b. He worked more rapidly than he usually does.

I use (b). I am not sure (a) is correct.

Comment: (a) is unidiomatic - we would say _more rapidly than usual_. (b) is OK because the adverb goes with the verb _does_.

Comment: What doubts do you have about these two sentences?

Comment: Thank you both very much. I didn't like (a) although it seems logical to me. It just sounds strange to my ears. Kate has confirmed my suspicion.